# garbage characters in buffer

Tags: c++, linux

I have this function.

```
void cast(char *buf)
{
    string str(buf);
    string  s=str.substr(0,5);
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),::toupper);
    DemoInput=s;
}
```

The *buf is a message that the client sends. I'm trying to take that message and no matter how long it is strip it to five characters and make it uppercase. This works if the message > 5 but if the message < 5 then there are garbage characters at the end of it.
ex: if buf is "long" then DemoInput becomes "LONG\\r"

I thought about using regex ("[:upper:]") but think there must be an easier way to do this.
I find posix regex a bit more complicated then python regex for example.

Comment: What do you want the function to do when the message is shorter than 5 characters? Should it add dummy characters at the end?

Comment: I what you say is really happening then you have found a bug. I suspect that your input is not null terminated however.

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger, or print out the input, to see that you get a valid input string?

Comment: @jogojapan if lets say the message is "hi" then just use those two letters and make it uppercase ("HI").

Comment: @john buf contains a message that the user has telneted to the server, the buf is null terminated before receiving the message but when it receives it it also receives those garbage characters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've debugged and the telneted message contains those garbage characters for some reason.

Comment: I don't know telnet but those garbage characters just seem to be a carriage return and a line feed. Can't you just remove them?

Comment: @john I'd like to remove them yes. I thought about using regex to find all uppercase characters in that string and extract them, don't know how to do it with posix regex tho.

Comment: You don't need anything so complex, this code `for (char *p = buf; *p; ++p) if (*p == '\r') { *p = '\0'; break; }` will remove `"\r\n"` from the end of `buf`. There are lots of other ways as well.

Comment: @john that seems to work, thanks!
If you want you can write that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @ogward I would look at Nikos' answer. His is the neater solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the first 5 characters, don't copy the whole of `buf`. That just wastes space and time. Also, you shouldn't copy anything past the telnet control character `\r`.

```
void cast(char *buf)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    while (len < 5 && buf[len] != '\0' && buf[len] != '\r') {
        ++len;
    }
    string s(buf, len);
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),::toupper);
    DemoInput=s;
}
```

Comment: That would be UB if buf was less than five characters.

Comment: if the telnet message is "out" then there are garbage characters added to it for some reason so it becomes "out//r//n" so this wont work because id like to remove those garbage characters and get "OUT"

Comment: @ogward OK, didn't know about the telnet thing. I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the code supplying the buf to the cast function. Append '\0' to signify end of string as it sounds though it may not be null terminated.

Comment: I thought about that so I looped through the buffer and added **'\0'** to every cell. It's when the telneted message is received that the garbage characters appear.